# Convert 3 output to one input at NODE-RED

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi3, node-red

Question is about Node-RED for raspberry pi 3. I have 3 input that give acceleration of X,Y,Z axis. I want to make one output from these 3 inputs. For this , I use  `√X^2+Y^2+Z^2` formula. According to my function my output is still 3 piece and giving **NaN** output when i debug. What should i do in Acc to Freq function

Here is my collecting X,Y,Z info from my sql.

```
var str = msg.payload;
str = str[0]['IX']; // Choose last data from IX column
a = str * 10;   // Scaling the value
msg.payload = a
return msg;
```

---

```
var str = msg.payload;
str = str[0]['IY']; // Choose last data from IY column
b = str * 10;   // Scaling the value
msg.payload = b
return msg;
```

---

```
var str = msg.payload;
str = str[0]['IZ']; // Choose last data from IZ column
c = str * 10;   // Scaling the value
msg.payload = c
return msg;
```

And the function that i m try to calculate one output ( Acc to Freq )

```
var str = msg.payload;
var a;
var b;
var c;

str = Math.pow(a^2+b^2+c^2);
d = str * 10;
msg.payload = d;
return msg;
```

[image]

Comment: Check if str is even a number. Tip: it's not.

Comment: I was calculate a,b,c, and they have value. Why these values not called in second function.?

Comment: Because functions are totally separate from each other.

Comment: It sounds like you already have a sql query returning the three values you need to do the calculation -- why not just add the calculation to the query, as the 4th value to be returned?

Comment: That's good point but I need to add calculation part for python code. It's ok but i got error, so im tried this way to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The point to remember is that a function node runs every time a message arrives, if you send it 3 separate messages then it will run 3 times. Also each function node is totally independent of all others, you can't declare a variable in one and use it in another (well there is something called the [Context](https://nodered.org/docs/configuration#functionGlobalContext), but that's not particularly useful here)

You've not actually shown your flow so we are going to have to guess a little here, but you imply that all the starting values are coming from a single SQL query that returns multiple columns. If this is the case then you have 2 options.

1. Just do all the calculations in one place e.g. one function node with the  following:

   ```
   var str = msg.payload;
   var strA = str[0]['IX']; // Choose last data from IX column
   var a = strA * 10;   // Scaling the value
   var strB = str[0]['IY']; // Choose last data from IY column
   var b = strB * 10;   // Scaling the value
   var strC = str[0]['IZ']; // Choose last data from IZ column
   var c = strC * 10;   // Scaling the value
   var strC = Math.pow(a^2+b^2+c^2);
   var d = strC * 10;
   msg.payload = d;
   return msg;
   ```
2. You can run the output of your current 3 function nodes into a `Join` node set to collect 3 values. This will generate a new msg object with a payload containing an array of the 3 values. You can then modify your final function node as follows:

   ```
   var a = msg.payload[0];
   var b = msg.payload[1];
   var c = msg.payload[2];
   var d = Math.pow(a^2+b^2+c^2) * 10 ;
   msg.payload = d;
   return msg;
   ```

Comment: hello, thanks for your advice , i tried it like that and im gettin still NaN , your advice is very clear to understand but why i'm still gettin NaN ?  BTW im adding my nodes as picture.

Comment: Then are you sure the query is returning numbers and not strings?

Comment: Yes im sure why ?